# get CCSprite on ccTouchesMoved

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

In cocos2d I have created many sprites dynamically and i need get the current touched sprite in the event method for drag and drop.

Using this method:

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just quick Google
   Try this...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d